# How do I fix issues with "composer dependencies" on a WordPress/Cpanel site?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, cpanel

Semi-inexperienced webmaster here running into a new problem. Recently, a client's website started displaying the following error:

*Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 5.6.0".*

Its a WordPress site hosted using NameCheap, with cPanel admin tools. All of the Wordpress stuff updates automatically but I can't say the same for the server itself.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it as simple as updating PHP on the server? Thanks!

-Lambus

Comment: If the server is running a PHP version lower than 7.2, then you should definitely upgrade it since version 7.1 and older are no longer supported  and doesn't even get security updates anymore. And by looking at the error, you're even using 5.5 or older! How to do that on a server hosted by NameCheap, you need to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced this problem with Namecheap, Basically, your terminal on the server is using a lower PHP version than the 5.6. You can't change the terminal PHP version.

**Solution**
You need to ask the Namecheap support team to upgrade it.